# Removing the extra padding in a GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview, cellpadding

I want to remove the extra padding that appears in a grid view. I have images of the size 128*128 which will be occupying cells in the grid. But somehow there is an extra space that gets added to the contents of the grid.

After some research, I was able to determine that I have to override the listSelector property of the grid view. Now here's my question - I know I have to specify something like an xml drawable here, but what to specify in that?? I tried using a shape drawable with padding and stroke set to 0dp to no avail.

The question is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684543/how-to-avoid-space-between-imageview-and-gridview-in-linearlayout), but they haven't given what the drawable must contain.

Can some one help me with this. Thanks!

EDIT: Ok - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM5I3.png)'s a copy of the UI that I have. And the XML layout for the same is as follows:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/GV_A2ZMenu" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numColumns="4"
            android:layout_gravity="top" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" android:listSelector="@null" />
```

And I am using a BaseAdapter class to populate the gridView. Here's its code:

```
public class AtoZMenu extends BaseAdapter {

private static Context AppC;

private Integer[] MenuImg = { R.drawable.alphabet_a, R.drawable.alphabet_b,
        R.drawable.alphabet_c, R.drawable.alphabet_d,
        R.drawable.alphabet_e, R.drawable.alphabet_f,
        R.drawable.alphabet_g, R.drawable.alphabet_h,
        R.drawable.alphabet_i, R.drawable.alphabet_j,
        R.drawable.alphabet_k, R.drawable.alphabet_l,
        R.drawable.alphabet_m, R.drawable.alphabet_n,
        R.drawable.alphabet_o, R.drawable.alphabet_p,
        R.drawable.alphabet_q, R.drawable.alphabet_r,
        R.drawable.alphabet_s, R.drawable.alphabet_t,
        R.drawable.alphabet_u, R.drawable.alphabet_v,
        R.drawable.alphabet_w, R.drawable.alphabet_x,
        R.drawable.alphabet_y, R.drawable.alphabet_z };

public AtoZMenu(Context C) {
    AppC = C;
}

public int getCount() {
    return MenuImg.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView IV;
    float density = AppC.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    if (convertView == null) {
        IV = new ImageView(AppC);
        IV.setMaxHeight((int) (1));
    } else {
        IV = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    IV.setImageResource(MenuImg[position]);
    return IV;
}
 }
```

Can you spot the mistake?

**Note:** In the end I ended up implementing a similar screen in a table layout which renders much better grids.

Comment: A sreenshot would help to understand the problem, along with your layout XML file

Comment: Have edited the question, it contains a link to a similar question which has been answered already, but its implementation is missing!

Comment: @MarvinLabs: I have posted the UI and the xml layout code that I have used for that as well. Can you figure out the problem??

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yep, I've had the same problem. You want to set the listSelector to @null:

```
<!-- Setting the listSelector to null removes the 5px border -->
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@null" />
```

Also, try the following:

```
myGridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
```

I see you can do this in the XML, but I didn't when I had this same problem; not sure why.

I also hard-coded the key height:

```
float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
mKeyHeight = (int) (56 * density);
....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) convertView;
    if (b == null) {
        b = new ImageButton(getContext());
        b.setMinimumHeight(mKeyHeight);
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_keyboard_key);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Sorry about not giving a precise answer, so let me know if you still need help after that.

Comment: Ah! Nope. I tried specifying it as null. It doesn't help. Anyways, I have included a screenshot of my UI and the code that i have used as well. See if you can find a flaw out of this..

Comment: If you added the code that you use to add the buttons, it might help.

Comment: Also, see another suggestion for setStretchMode, which I did when I had the same problem.

Comment: So basically this is like hard coding both the width and the height?? Let me check out this solution and come back to you.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong. And also, what does "56" signify? BTW - I tried setting a MinHeight and also MaxHeight. It doesn't seem to effect anything. As u can see, I have it set as 1, still doesn't make any difference!

Comment: Is that XML file the entire file? Is it possible your view is getting stretch somehow? I copied your code basically as is, and I do get a little padding at the top and bottom of each image but not padding to the left and right, but in any case not nearly as much as you're seeing.

Comment: You could instead use a 9-patch and do setBackgroundResource instead of setImageResource, which might do a better job of stretching to fill the extra space.

Comment: That remaining part of that XML is a relative layout with a header on top.. Let me try out your last suggestion!

Comment: @Shawn Lauzon - This was so frustrating. Thx for this.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is to set `android:listSelector` to `@android:color/transparent`, as user **mvds** said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053458/1066739).

Answer (score 1):

I used a variation of Shawn's solution.. it looks nice on the Emulator.

1) Decide on the # of columns, I chose 4

2) Set the Column Width

```
float xdpi = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
int mKeyHeight = (int) ( xdpi/4 );

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview); 
gridView.setColumnWidth( mKeyHeight );// same Height & Width
```

3) Setup the image in your adapter's getView method

```
imageView = new ImageView( mContext );
// (xdpi-4) is for internal padding
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams( (int) (xdpi-4)/2, (int) (xdpi-4)/2));
imageView.setScaleType( ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP );
imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

4) Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="@null"
/>
<!-- 
    android:columnWidth="90dp"  Specified in code 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" no noticable change
-->
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem.
Try this:

`image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth , imageHeight));
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`.

Add padding accordingly for the images.It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, though in my case there was a quite large padding area at the bottom of my `GridView` (it was filled with the background color).
I haven't seen the solution to my issue here, so I'll post it here in case it's helpful.

Besides setting:

```
android:listSelector="@null"
```

in my GridView, I also had to set:

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
```

Or, in Java:

```
GridView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give padding in pixels like this

```
  android:paddingLeft="5px"
```