# Removing the margin/padding from the Entry in Xamarin Android via styles.xml

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-styles, xamarin.forms.entry

According to another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44596938/25282) it's possible to remove the margin of a normal `Button` via `styles.xml`.

I would like to do the same for the margin/padding of `Entry`. Given that my trivial assumption would be that it uses an EditText beneath I tried:

```
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyEditText</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
  </style>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't have any effect. Even when I use `50dip` as a value there's no effect. What are the correct setting in `styles.xml` to affect the `Entry`-widgit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainTheme.Base`

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
```

And your `@style/EditTextStyle`

```
<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

**Note:** This going to depend upon your layout, as the "margins" are to parent Android layout containers (`ViewGroup`) and thus your Forms' Entry might not be effected. If you are not sure that you have set this up correctly, throw a color into the style to double check, something like all Entries having Green text:

```
<item name="android:textColor">#00f000</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that it's padding and not margins but the styling works well.